# Arch Linux + Gnome: Wine going berserk on "open with" menu

Tags: gnome, arch-linux, wine

First of all, when I installed Wine on my system, it decided to automatically associate its "notepad" application with all types of text and image files. This was annoying enough, but on top of that, whenever I choose the "open with" dialog, I find that Wine has filled it with hundreds of duplicate entries. Most of them are just labeled "A Wine application" with no icon, but any time I install another program with Wine, it adds 5-10 entries for that application as well. How do I fix or disable this?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/323437/how-to-prevent-wine-from-adding-file-associations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This might be useful  for you.](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-c847a3ded88bac0e61aae0037fa7dbd4c7ae042a)

Comment: Good find. Can you summarize the link in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

you can remove all the crap by editing `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` - in my install there's never anything but wine-created crap in there, so I just trash it altogether.

How to stop wine doing it in the first place?  Dunno, sorry!